# Excel VBA: Add data to cell after last used row

Tags: vba, excel

[image]
The pic shows what happens with my code.

I have a user form and I add the labels of the user form into the selected worksheet. And this is what I tried. Now the problem is why is it that there is one cell not on the same row as the others?

```
Dim c As Control
For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "Label" Then
        With ActiveSheet
            i = i + 1
            Dim lastRow As Long
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

            If c <> "Chapter" Then
                .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, i)).Name = "Chapter1"
                .Range("Chapter1").Merge
                .Range("Chapter1").Value = "Chapter 1"
                .Range("Chapter1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

                .Cells(lastRow, i).Value = c.Caption
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next
```

Comment: if you want the **blank** cell after the last used row (= last row filled with dada) then use `lastRow + 1` because `lastRow` represents the last row filled with data.

Comment: This happens with the + 1

Comment: So I can't guess what you are trying to achieve, you need to tell us your goal. Describe what your code actually does and what you expect it to do please.

Comment: Okay. I edited my question. I'm not sure if that is understandable though. I'm having a hard time explaining what I want to happen.

Comment: There are lots of merged cells in row 1. So, when lastrow = 1 in your loop, you would effectively be trying to write to various cells in the merged range. That isn't possible. You can only write in the first cell. Therefore check the value of lastrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the first time you do `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` there will not be anything yet in A2, so `lastRow` will be 1. But once you put the value "No." in that cell the next time you execute that code (with `i` being 2), A2 will be filled, so now `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` will return 2, giving you the effect you get: all other values end up one row lower.

There are several way to solve this, but here is one way. Add `+ IIf(i = 1, 1, 0)` the assignment of `lastRow`:

```
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + IIf(i = 1, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much. This worked for me. And I understood what is happening to my code through your explanation. Thank you so much. Now I'll research about the IIf you just told me to use to understand what happened. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome ;-) The `IIf` will add 1 to the result when `i = 1`, otherwise it will add nothing ( 0 ). It is like an `If ... Then ...  Else ...` statement, but then in a form you can use in an expression.

Comment: Okay. I understand now. Thank you so much.